# Working with Drupal and Scrum

Tags: drupal, agile, scrum

Looking for resources for success working on Drupal sites in a Scrum model, particularly in the early phases of a project.

Presently our projects transition from discovery to wireframes to design to execution. In the process, of course, requirements often change which requires time-consuming "loops" back through IA and design if they are at all substantive - affecting both budget and timeline.

One of the tenets of Scrum is that each sprint should result in something potentially shippable. We've experimented with creating functional (but ugly) prototypes first, and then applying theming, but the results are, of course, not exactly something I'd be excited to show a customer, especially those customers that are somewhat new to managing web projects and unfamiliar with the process.

I've found surprisingly little information in this area - plenty on what Scrum is and how to apply it to traditional software - very little on applying it to the web, and especially large hairy CMSes like Drupal - any articles, books, resources, etc? Or do you have a story to tell of how you've succeeded?

Comment: This presentation may help you http://docs.google.com/Presentation?id=ajksfggkdk7q_2007gjb85fcp but you should make your own mind with real experiences... this is not a direct "how to" question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (Unfortunately, this question is too old to be  migrated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out the book [Leveraging Drupal: Getting Your Site Done Right](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470410876), which doesn't mention scrum specifically, but does include an entire chapter on agile approaches to building Drupal sites.

There's a DrupalCamp Stockholm presentation [video on Using Scrum to Manage Drupal Projects](http://robpurdie.net/2010/01/30/video-drupalcamp-stockholm). Or there's the [Intro to Agile and Scrum session](http://vimeo.com/6595062) from DrupalCamp Dallas.

Not specifically scrum, but other agile presentations include the [video](http://www.archive.org/details/drupalconchi_day3_lessons_learned_from_the_agile) from the recent DrupalCon Chicago session on [Lessons Learned from the Agile Process Applied](http://chicago2011.drupal.org/sessions/lessons-learned-agile-process-applied). Or check out the [Agile is Not 'Cowboy' Spelled Backwards presentation](http://dogstar.org/drupal/content/agile-not-cowboy-spelled-backwards-more-drupalcamp-colorado) from Drupalcamp Colorado.

Answer (score 2):

The "potentially shippable" tenent in Scrum is all about two things:

1. Making sure that your team is completing work... that work is really done.
2. And, if you if you can ship it to customers, you'll learn more from their feedback than you would have from any long-term planning you did prior to the sprint.

I think the key in your situation is ensuring that items being brought to the team from the backlog are sized appropriately... so your team can finish them completely in a sprint (this would include styling, theming, etc).  If you're doing a bunch of sprints that are only resulting in prototypes, or half-finished requirements, you're not really doing Scrum.  Try decomposing your backlog items into smaller pieces so that they can be "done done" at the end of sprint.

This is a transition I've seen many teams go through, and the move to smaller backlog items always helps.